# Find numbers $a_n$ such that $a_n > a_{n+1}$ and $a_n, a_{n+1}$ that satisfies the inequality $a_n \geq \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + a_{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation, proof-writing, induction

I'm working on a project for my introduction to abstract math course and I'm stuck on a particular part of it. We're supposed to prove $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} < \frac{7}{4}$ using induction, and the project has us use the stronger inequality of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{7}{4} - a_n$, with $a_1, a_2, \: \cdots \:, a_n,\: \cdots $ being positive numbers such that the inequality is true for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. I found an inequality that I could use to come up with something for $a_n$, which is $a_n \geq \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + a_{n+1}$. Here's where I got stuck, as I don't know what would be a good sequence to define $a_n$ as that would make proving $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k^2} \leq \frac{7}{4} - a_{n+1}$ the easiest, or even what sequence to use at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From experience, I know that $$\displaystyle\sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k^2} < \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{k(k-1)} = \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{k-1}-\dfrac{1}{k}\right) = \dfrac{1}{n}.$$ So I'd recommend trying something like $a_n = \dfrac{1}{n}$. See if you can verify that $$a_n = \dfrac{1}{n} \ge \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\dfrac{1}{n+1} = \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}+a_{n+1}$$ for all $n$. Note that when you write up your proof, you may have to start your base case at $n = 2$ or something instead of the usual $n = 1$.

Comment: I'm confused by how you wrote the sums, none of what I'm doing uses infinite sums, or is that there because of a particular property of them or something?

Comment: Induction typically requires you to make some guess as to the formula you want to prove. In this case, you need to guess what numbers $a_n$ to use. I'm suggesting that you use $a_n = 1/n$ due to how the tail of the infinite sum $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\tfrac{1}{k^2}$ behaves. Of course, writing a proof by induction doesn't require that you justify why you chose a particular sequence of numbers $a_n$.

Comment: In particular, the tail sums $S_n = \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty}\tfrac{1}{(k+1)^2}$ satisfy $S_n = \tfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}+S_{n+1}$, so you need numbers $a_n$ that behave similarly as the tail sums.